# Google Chrome sign in in school laboratory computers

Tags: google-chrome, login

When I'm using the computers in my school's computer laboratory, I used to sign in my Google account for the Chrome and let it to retrieve my configurations (such as favorites and history). However sometimes I forget to sign out the Google Account.

Will other users can access to my Google account and its data using their own computer accounts?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question... If your question is: "do I need to sign out to prevent people from having access to my stuff" then the answer is DEFINITELY

Comment: Yes, something like that. However I'm wondering if I forgot to log off, then will other users that log in with different user names  also get access to my google account?

Comment: What OS do you use? Do I understand well that everybody has his own account and you logoff before leaving the computer? If it's set up properly then you don't need to worry.

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 Enterprise. Everyone would log out/ shutdown after using the computer

Comment: If you forget to sign out of chrome you will probably also forget to sign out of Windows ...

Comment: Alright, is that means Google account sign in for Chrome is only dependent with a particular windows user in that computer?

Comment: ohh, i think i understand now. Yes, google chrome user data corrosponds to the windows user account. There is no need to sign out of google chrome if you sign out of the computer itself